# Why do people in central Switzerland say "Grüzach" instead of Grüezi?

Tags: salutation, swiss-german, swiss-standard-german

Grüezi is the most common greeting in Switzerland. However, each canton has its own dialect making verbal speech (and local spellings) different in different parts of the country.

In central Switzerland near Thunersee, I was often greeted with "Grüezach" instead of Grüezi. What explains this pronounciation or intonation on the last syllable? Pretty sure they'd even spell it "Grüezagg" or "Grüezegg" since my spelling above was only a guess.

How is Grüezi spoken and spelled in other parts of Switzerland?

Comment: unfortunately only in German: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCezi

Comment: The title of your post is a very different question from the question you state in inside the post. Please help others help you and clarify what is it exactly that you would like to know.

Comment: It's *Grüß euch.* That *euch* becomes *i*, *ach* or *egg* depending on dialect.

Comment: @janka could u form an answer with meaning of euch here, and alternative pronounciations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit** Updated answer, to remove the obviously wrong reference pointed out in the other answer.

Janka has given the correct hint: It's actually *Grüss Euch*, which is pronounced short as *Grüssech*. In some regions of Switzerland (mainly near Berne, but also towards Basel) people do not `Siezen` but `Ihrzen`. The formal address is not `Sie` (third person plural), but `Ihr/Euch` (second person plural), which makes the term understandable.

Example: Instead of saying

> Ich werde Sie anrufen

one says

> Ich werde Euch anrufen.

Note that this is still about a single person, addressed formally, not a group. The difference works in Swiss German, too.

Since Swiss German is not used as formal written language, there are no official rules about it's spelling, too. Everyone basically writes how he thinks it should be (and since the dialects differ significantly from place to place, there are a lot of different spellings)

The boundaries between the dialects and hence the pronunciations are floating. Almost every word has different pronunciations across Switzerland, some of which can be found on [this page](http://dialektkarten.ch/mapviewer/swg/index.de.html#dominance:3209_euch) (selected: the different pronunciations of "Euch"). As you can see on those different maps, the borders don't line up with any political borders and differ from word to word. In fact, while ["Gruessech" is used in all of Berne](http://dialektkarten.ch/mapviewer/swg/index.de.html#dominance:5112_gruss), it's only the southern part (and Wallis) that [commonly uses the "iir" form](http://dialektkarten.ch/mapviewer/swg/index.de.html#dominance:5117_Anrede).

If you enter a set of phrases in your local dialect, that website will tell you very precisely where you originate from.

Comment: are you aware of the specific differences on how *gruess euch* is pronounced per canton? If so, edit it in above. And is the Swiss usage of *euch* in this context viewed as non-standard by high Germans?

Comment: @user610620 Updated. Found a good website indicating the wide range of different dialect forms in Switzerland.

Comment: they say "Grueziir" in the south? didn't stay long enough there to even notice

Comment: @user610620 the dialect in the (German part of) Wallis is hardly understandable to anyone...

Comment: I am afraid this explanation is wrong. The difference between «grüessech» and «grüezi» has nothing to do with use of _Ihrzen_ or _Siezen._ Both words correspond to standard German _grüss Euch._

Answer (score 4):

Both «grüezi» and «grüessech» have the exact same etymology. They both correspond to standard German *grüess Euch*. There are two reasons for their different forms:

1. In western Swiss German, the verb ‘to greet’ is pronounced with a fortis /sː/ as /ɡ̊ryə̯sːə/ («grüesse»), but in eastern Swiss German, it is (originally) pronounced with an affricate /ts/ as /ɡ̊ryə̯tsə/ («grüeze»).
2. In western Swiss German, the second person plural accusative or dative pronoun (standard German «euch») ends with a fricative /x/ as /øi̯x/ or /əx/ («euch»/«ech»), but in eastern Swiss German, there is no fricative: /oi̯/ or /i/ («eu»/«i»).

This means that standard German «grüss Euch» corresponds to «grüess Ech» in western Swiss German, but to «grüez I» in eastern Swiss German.

There are two complications:

- The dialect that is known best for using «grüessech», Bernese German, is also known for using the second person plural as honorific («Ihr/Euch», hence *Ihrzen),* whereas the dialects that use «grüezi» typically use the third person plural as honorific («Si» or standard German «Sie», hence *Siezen).* This leads to a common folk etymology whereby the difference between «grüezi» and «grüessech» has to do with the use of the third or second person plural as honorific. By that folk etymology, «grüezi» corresponds to standard German *grüss Sie,* but «grüessech» corresponds to standard German *grüss Euch.* That folk etymology is mistaken. Both «grüessech» and «grüezi» correspond to standard German *grüss Euch* (cf. [Grüezi - Schweizerisches Idiotikon](https://www.idiotikon.ch/wortgeschichten/grueezi)). The use of the second or third person plural as honorific *(Ihrzen* or *Siezen)* has nothing to do with the difference between «grüessech» and «grüezi».
- The original eastern Swiss German form «grüeze» with an affricate is often being replaced by a form with a fricative «grüesse». The reason is probably the influence from standard German «grüssen». Since the form «grüeze» is no longer familiar to many speakers, the word «grüezi» is no longer etymologically transparent to them.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I really fell for this one. I removed that reference from my answer, the rest still holds, I believe.

Comment: Could either of you recommend a standard text (and slightly technical) on exact Swiss dialect annunciations, covering all Swiss-german speaking cantons? A thorough audio guide of any medium to accompany selected writings would be great. The answer here must've come from a resplendent source(s) I'm guessing. unless it is only the idiotikon linked.

Comment: @PMF: The bulk of your answer still discusses topics like _Siezen/Ihrzen_ that are completely unrelated to _Grüessech_ vs. _Grüezi_. Also, while you explain that _Grüessech_ corresponds to standard German «grüss euch», you omit that _Grüezi_ also corresponds to standard German «grüss euch».

Comment: @user610620: The [Idiotikon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerisches_Idiotikon) is one of the very best resources on Swiss German, and certainly the most comprehensive, being a 17-volume dictionary with about 150.000 entries.